# Tables not resizing to browser windows, defying margins

Tags: html, css

Thanks for helping!  I am new at this site, so the post may look funny.

Bascially to refresh and iron out my HTML/CSS skills before heading into PHP/Javascript, I created this crappy simple site to play with most of what I know, to make sure I can make it do what I want it to at least.

I appear to be able to, except for tables.  They wont resize based on browser windows, and ignore their margins...

I'll do my best to put my code in here properly.  Apologies, I was taught that doing all CSS in separate documents was the proper way to do it, but it makes it a bit difficult here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Test Page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav id="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="another_page.html">Application</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 </header>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <h2>This website is a basic test to refresh skills, you can apply to be a real developer on the next page.</h2>
  <img src="img/moneynerd.jpg" alt="Money web developing earns" class="frontpagepic">
  <table border="2" id="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th>Web Development</th>
     <th>Being a loser</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr>
    <td>Money</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>No</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Time</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>No</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Happiness</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>No</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Family</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>No</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Toys</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>No</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Worth it</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>No</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 <footer>
  <p>removed for forum post</p>
 </footer>
 </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

```css
/**************************************
GENERAL
**************************************/
h2 {
text-align:center;
color: #0000bb;
margin: 2% 0 0 0;
}

#gallery img {
max-width: 21%;
margin: 0 2.9% 0 2.9%;
}


#breakhere {
float: right;
}

/*Table sizing is an issue.... Forum: */
#table {
text-align: center;
max-width:16.17%; 
margin: 0 41.915% 0 41.915%;
}


/**************************************
NAV
**************************************/


#nav {
text-align: center;
}

nav a {
text-decoration: none;
}

nav li {
margin: 0;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
}
 #nav ul li a {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 }



/**************************************
FOOTER
**************************************/


footer {
font-size: 1em;
clear:both;
text-align: center;
padding-top:3px;
} 
footer a {
text-decoration: none;
}
footer a, footer img {
margin: .5%;
}

/**************************************
COLORS
**************************************/
nav a, nav a:visited {
color: #0000ff;
}
nav a.selected {
color: #66E0FF;
}
nav a:hover {
color: #00CCFF;
}

/**************************************
MAIN
**************************************/

.frontpagepic {
max-width: 50%;
margin: 4% 25% 4% 25%;
}

/**************************************
ANOTHER_PAGE
**************************************/


/**************************************
SUBMITTED
**************************************/
```

```css
/*! normalize.css v1.1.0 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

/* ==========================================================================
   HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Correct `block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
    display: block;
}

/**
 * Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

audio,
canvas,
video {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3, and Safari 4.
 * Known issue: no IE 6 support.
 */

[hidden] {
    display: none;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Base
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE 6/7 when body `font-size` is set using
 *    `em` units.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address `font-family` inconsistency between `textarea` and other form
 * elements.
 */

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/**
 * Address margins handled incorrectly in IE 6/7.
 */

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Links
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Typography
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address font sizes and margins set differently in IE 6/7.
 * Address font sizes within `section` and `article` in Firefox 4+, Safari 5,
 * and Chrome.
 */

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0.83em 0;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.17em;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 1.33em 0;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 0.83em;
    margin: 1.67em 0;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 0.67em;
    margin: 2.33em 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Safari 5, and Chrome.
 */

abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

/**
 * Address style set to `bolder` in Firefox 3+, Safari 4/5, and Chrome.
 */

b,
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

blockquote {
    margin: 1em 40px;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 */

dfn {
    font-style: italic;
}

/**
 * Address differences between Firefox and other browsers.
 * Known issue: no IE 6/7 normalization.
 */

hr {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 6/7/8/9.
 */

mark {
    background: #ff0;
    color: #000;
}

/**
 * Address margins set differently in IE 6/7.
 */

p,
pre {
    margin: 1em 0;
}

/**
 * Correct font family set oddly in IE 6, Safari 4/5, and Chrome.
 */

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
    font-family: monospace, serif;
    _font-family: 'courier new', monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

/**
 * Improve readability of pre-formatted text in all browsers.
 */

pre {
    white-space: pre;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

/**
 * Address CSS quotes not supported in IE 6/7.
 */

q {
    quotes: none;
}

/**
 * Address `quotes` property not supported in Safari 4.
 */

q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent and variable font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
    font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` affecting `line-height` in all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
    top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
    bottom: -0.25em;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Lists
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address margins set differently in IE 6/7.
 */

dl,
menu,
ol,
ul {
    margin: 1em 0;
}

dd {
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}

/**
 * Address paddings set differently in IE 6/7.
 */

menu,
ol,
ul {
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}

/**
 * Correct list images handled incorrectly in IE 7.
 */

nav ul,
nav ol {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 * 2. Improve image quality when scaled in IE 7.
 */

img {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Correct overflow displayed oddly in IE 9.
 */

svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Figures
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 6/7/8/9, Safari 5, and Opera 11.
 */

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Correct margin displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

form {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Correct text not wrapping in Firefox 3.
 * 3. Correct alignment displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

legend {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal; /* 2 */
    *margin-left: -7px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct font size not being inherited in all browsers.
 * 2. Address margins set differently in IE 6/7, Firefox 3+, Safari 5,
 *    and Chrome.
 * 3. Improve appearance and consistency in all browsers.
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 3 */
    *vertical-align: middle; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 3+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

button,
input {
    line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Chrome, Safari 5+, and IE 6+.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox 4+ and Opera.
 */

button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 * 4. Remove inner spacing in IE 7 without affecting normal text inputs.
 *    Known issue: inner spacing remains in IE 6.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
    *overflow: visible;  /* 4 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

/**
 * 1. Address box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Remove excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
    *height: 13px; /* 3 */
    *width: 13px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
 * on OS X.
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 3+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Improve readability and alignment in all browsers.
 */

textarea {
    overflow: auto; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: top; /* 2 */
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Tables
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

I haven't actually implemented "responsive.css" yet, so that will have no effect.

The result at full screen, is fine, however when I resize the window, the size of the table does not change, and the margin does not adjust dynamically, so the table is off to the right for some reason.  Sorry, I would post a picture, but I don't have the reputation yet apparently :P

I've tried setting the max-width to 100% while commenting out my custom #table attributes, which most forums say should make it dynamic with the window, however it hasn't affected it.  Is there a conflict i'm not seeing?

Any help you could provide is amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the `td` to percentages. 
If you are looking for a mobile friendly approach then i recommend to [Responsive tables from css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)